# Como fazer um banner rotativo em JS com array

Tags: javascript

Estou iniciando no JS e gostaria de fazer banner rotativo colocando as imagens dentro de um vetor ao invés de fazer como no código abaixo:

```
function slide1(){
   document.getElementById("banner").src = "img/banner9.png";
   setTimeout(slide2,1000);
}

function slide2(){
   document.getElementById("banner").src = "img/banner8.png";
   setTimeout(slide1,1000);
}
```

Seria injusto eu pedir pra vocês me darem o código, então vocês têm alguma orientação de onde eu posso pesquisar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O nome é carousel. Recomendo que use o [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) ou o [Owl Carousel](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/demos.html). São bem leves e simples de implementar. Não há necessidade de reinventar a roda.